# HEVC wrong number of frames after decoding

Tags: hevc, h.265

I have a .yuv 420 video which I want to encode and decode back with HEVC codec. But after decoding, video misses 4 frames (it was 30, became 26). While encoding I get such an error:

```
Assertion failed: (iNumPicRcvd > 0), function xInitGOP, file TEncGOP.cpp, line 2382.
```

While decoding I get such an error:

```
Assertion failed: (m_fifo_idx < m_fifo.size()), function readByte, file TComBitStream.h, line 191.
```

Answer (score 0):

I specified an incorrect video height and width in .cfg file. Changing these values -- helped for me